# Sending vehicle specific OBDII commands

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, obd-ii

Has anyone successfully sent a vehicle specific OBDII command through Bluetooth? I'm working on a Android app that sends OBDII commands to a OBDII Bluetooth adapter that will be connected to the cars OBDII port. But when I want to send a vehicle specific command with [pires API](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) I get `NO DATA` back as an answer. I've tested his other commands such as Voltage and they all work.

Any ideas?

**edit:** I've tested the troubleshooting codes in the README and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you look into the portion in the troubleshooting section of the README?

Comment: nope, tested that and did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the OBD adapter... I changed it to a different one, and now it works.

Comment: Hi Swess
Can you share your code with me ?  I am new in this OBD II communication protocol and looking something for a quick startup  **ch.zahid.ge@gmail.com**